# Entity Framework List Contains in lambda

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I want to query items with specific IDs using. For example:

```
var ids = new List<int> { 1, 3, 5 };

var items = context.Items.Where(item => ids.Contains(item.ID)).ToList();
```

Questions:

1. Will this generate a single query with SQL `IN` operator?
2. Is this code OK in terms of performance?
3. Are there any better ways to do it?

I am using Entity Framework 6 with Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: yes, Contains() is supported in EF6 and will be translated to IN. I don't think there is any more performant way to do it.

Comment: It depends. If this list is also coming from the database then the best way to handle it is a join statement in SQL instead of an IN which can be done using a couple of different techniques in EF (.Any is one of them). If the list is small then performance is usually not an issue, if the list is extensive it can cause performance problems.

Comment: I would say there is no easier way to do this. The performance can be worse depending on **your database**, the complexity of the query (joining, grouping, ...) and finally the size of your local list. I would avoid using local list by designing the database as well as possible. The local list if used should have small size.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Will this generate a single query with SQL IN operator?
   Yes
2. Is this code OK in terms of performance?
   Yes (for small lists)
3. Are there any better ways to do it?
   No (for small lists)

If the list is really big and the table is reasonably small you might get better performance bringing the complete table into memory and do an in memory join with the list.

Comment: SQL IN will be generated only if the provider supports it. Sql Server providers supports it but Oracle provider doesn't

Comment: For me this brings the entire table in, then grabs the values it needs from memory. Considering the table has ~15 million rows, this is crippling performance wise. It pretty much performs a `SELECT * FROM` query without an `IN`.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell Perhaps you are using an older version of EF. Or using non SQL-Server provider.

Comment: @Magnus I'm using EF Core (7) right now. I may be missing this sort of functionality.

Comment: Hi @DouglasGaskell. If you are using EF Core 3.1+, you may find my work useful: https://github.com/yv989c/BlazarTech.QueryableValues