# LINQ/Lambda to select records with any Collection item matching any dynamic array element

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Using MVC 5 and C#. Front end allows selecting multiple Roles by name and sends them to the controller as a CSV string. The Controller then filters Users by their Roles property.

The frontend refers to the roles by `Role.Name` property although the roles saved in a User profile are referred to by `Role.Id`.

For example frontend submits, `"Customer,Employee,Administrator"`

In the Controller I need to select only those Users who are in these roles.

```
// Get users
var filteredRecords = UserManager.Users.AsQueryable();

// Get requested roles (HTTP POST)
string[] roleNames = model.RoleNames.Split(new string[] {","});
```

I can get an individual `Role.Id` with:

```
RoleManager.Roles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == roleName).Id
```

How can I use LINQ/Lambda efficiently to translate `roleNames` to an Array or List of `roleIds` and then how do I use that Array/List to filter only users contained in those roles?

Comment: a) Don't use `AsQueryable`. b) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745399/entity-framework-list-contains-in-lambda

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework List Contains in lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745399/entity-framework-list-contains-in-lambda)

Comment: @mjwills How does your reference provide help in translating the Role.Name to Role.Id? Also, User.Roles is a Collection of Role.Id - your reference doesn't filter a Collection on an Array/List.

Comment: `var ids = RoleManager.Roles.Where(r => roleNames.Contains(r.RoleName)).Select(z => z.Id).ToList()` will translate the names to IDs. Then I suspect you would do something like `UserManager.Users(z => ids.Contains(z.RoleId))` to get the users with those roles. Does that work?

Comment: @mjwills `User.Roles` is a Collection. It can't be referenced by `z.RoleId`. The Collection has to be iterated, I think with Any()?

Comment: Does `UserManager.Users(z => z.Roles.Any(y => ids.Contains(y.RoleId)))` work?

Comment: How much of the frontend are you able to change? I'd suggest first looking into passing the IDs instead of the names; rather than modifying the query to use the name. Are the role names _guaranteed_ to be unique? Are you making sure no name is allowed to contain a comma? Also, as an aside, MVC is able to give you an _array_ of names (or IDs) instead of you having to generate a comma-separated string with values, which would simplify the needed logic.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this one;

var reqRoles = model.RoleNames.Split(new string[] {","}).ToList();

var findRoles = RolesManager.Roles.Where(r => reqRoles.Contains(r.Name)).Select(r => r.Id).ToList();

Then you can find users by role ids.

Writing from mobile, sorry for maybe syntax error.

Answer (score -2):

I think Contains should work.

```
string[] input = new string[] { "A", "B", "C" };
string[] dataset = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
List<string> output = dataset.Where(x => input.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

Just in case you may confronting an object based dataset, the concept is the same and you can try

```
public class SimpleSet
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public SimpleSet(int id, string name)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
public void Execute()
{
    string[] input = new string[] { "A", "B", "C" };
    //string[] dataset = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };

    List<SimpleSet> dataset = new List<SimpleSet>();
    dataset.Add(new SimpleSet(1, "A"));
    dataset.Add(new SimpleSet(2, "B"));
    dataset.Add(new SimpleSet(3, "C"));
    dataset.Add(new SimpleSet(4, "D"));
    dataset.Add(new SimpleSet(5, "E"));

    List<SimpleSet> output = dataset.Where(x => input.Contains(x.name)).ToList();

    List<string> output_namesOnly = dataset.Where(x => input.Contains(x.name)).Select(x => x.name).ToList();

    List<int> output_idsOnly = dataset.Where(x => input.Contains(x.name)).Select(x => x.id).ToList();
}
```

Comment: This completely misses the crux of the question: _"How can I use LINQ/Lambda efficiently to **translate roleNames to an Array or List of roleIds** and then how do I use that Array/List to filter only users contained in those roles?"_

Comment: I just think the main idea is to apply Contains. But the output list for namesOnly is added for your understanding. Thanks

Comment: You're still not answering the question. At best, you're answering how to get all roles with any of the given names, but you're still not answering how to retrieve the subsequent users. This is not an answer, it's a bad example of a basic functionality with no explanation as to how it solves the posted issue.

Comment: I think md had already provided that he can send an string array to backend function (which is the parameter `input` of the above code). The issue is how to get the filtered dataset from the input string array.

Comment: I doubt if the explanation really required. my suggestion is just using Contains in the LINQ, so that you can find exact match between source dataset and input dataset, and filter out the dataset for the output. And you are correct that I missed the requirement of `an Array or List of roleIds`