# EF select based on list<int>

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

How to select from table based on `List<int>`.

Below, `AdminProfileRight` table contains column `MenuItemId(datatype INT)` and i want to select `AdminProfileRights` based on `menuIds` which is `List<int>`

```
public async Task Save(int profileId, int moduleId, int menuGroupId, List<AdminProfileRight> profileRights)
        {
            List<int> menuIds = profileRights.Select(pr => pr.MenuItemId).ToList();

            IEnumerable<AdminProfileRight> existingProfileRights = await _unitOfWork.Repository<AdminProfileRight>().GetAll(epr => epr.ProfileId == profileId);
            var itemsToDelete = existingProfileRights.Where(d => d.MenuItemId.Contains(menuIds));
        }
```

Howevever i see below compilation error.

```
CS1929  'int' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'MemoryExtensions.Contains<List<int>>(ReadOnlySpan<List<int>>, List<int>)' requires a receiver of type 'ReadOnlySpan<List<int>>'
```

Comment: `.Where(d => menuIds.Contains(d.MenuItemId))`. Also, it would be more performant to use `ToHashSet()` rather than `ToList()`, so that `Contains` has `O(1)` complexity rather than `O(n)`.

Comment: Hint. `MenuItemId` seems to be an `int`. And `menuIds` is definitely a collection of `int`'s.

Comment: You didn't post any EF Core code, just what looks like an implementation of an antipattern. Your code seems to be loading an entire table in memory or at least a lot of unrelated items, only to filter them in memory. What are your *actual* entities and DbContext? Why don't you use `myContext.Profiles.Where(p=>p.ProfileId==profileId && menuIds.Contains(p.MenuItemId))` ? Or, if `profileRights` already contains the items you want, why not filter *profileRights*?

Comment: You can try this.
`existingProfileRights.Where(d => menuIds.Any(c=> c == d.MenuItemId))`

Comment: @Tyson That's just a verbose alternative to `Contains`.

Comment: @Tyson EF Core translates `Contains(d.MenuItemId)` to `menuItemId in (1,2,5,...)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so using Any is bad practice or wrong.

Comment: A DbContext is already a multi-entity Unit-of-Work, a DbSet is already a single-entity Repository. They don't need wrapping in objects that say so. Your code broke both EF Core and LINQ , by loading a lot of objects that aren't needed in memory. If that `_unitOfWork` uses database transactions the code introduces serious concurrency problems as well

Comment: @Tyson in this case, bad and wrong. You need to understand what the code you wrote does. If EF Core actually generated a query using `ANY()` you'd end up with a very inefficient query. It's only because EF Core translates that `Any` to `Contains` that you get the efficient `IN (...)` syntax.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay _"Also, it would be more performant to use ToHashSet())"_ Is that true for EF Core? I can imagine the speedup in C#, but how does that map to SQL?

Comment: @JHBonarius That was based on the assumption that `GetAll` returns an in-memory collection rather than an `IQueryable`.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your last line with this:

```
var itemsToDelete = existingProfileRights.Where(d => menuIds.Contains(d.MenuItemId));
```

Look at [another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745399/entity-framework-list-contains-in-lambda)

Answer (score 0):

If you want determine whether the `List<T>` contains elements that is matched the conditions defined by the specified predicate you can use [`Exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.exists?view=net-6.0). In your case, you just want to determine whether an element is in the list you can use [`Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=net-6.0).

```
var itemsToDelete = existingProfileRights.Where(d => menuIds.Contains(d.MenuItemId));
```

This is how you use `Contains()`.